# How to access cookie across MVC views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my MVC app I am trying to store a cookie in one page response and access it another:

So my `/account/register` controller has an action that calls a method to store a cookie

```
public void StoreCookie(Guid pid)
{
        var userCookie = new HttpCookie("Userid","B6EAF085-247B-46EB-BB94-79779CA44A14");
        Response.Cookies.Remove("Userid");
        Response.Cookies.Add(userCookie);
    }
```

After a user registers I can see that the response(/account/register ) contains the cookie: `Userid:"B6EAF085-247B-46EB-BB94-79779CA44A14`

I now wish to access this cookie from another MVC page view -  `info/paymentsuccess`

I tried assigning the value to  `Viewbag` as

```
Viewbag.userid = @Response.Cookies["Userid"].value
```

This returns `null`

how do I access this cookie from another page/MVC view and store it in `Viewbag.userid`?

Answer (score 1):

In your account register controller set the cookie:

```
HttpCookie cookie = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Userid"];
this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

You can retrieve the cookie like so in your post /account/register controller:

```
if (this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("Userid"))
{
    HttpCookie cookie = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Userid"];
    // retrieve cookie data here
}
```

Comment: I am getting cannot resolve symbol error on the ControllerContext

Comment: Try Request.Cookies["Userid"]

Comment: The value is still null

Comment: Thanks Andrew but one point. I am accessing the cookie from a different view which uses a different controller

Comment: Ah, OK. Looking at your code again I think you might just need to change this:Viewbag.userid = @Response.Cookies["Userid"].value to this: Viewbag.userid = @Request.Cookies["Userid"].value

Answer (score 0):

You can access cookies value in your view using following:

```
  Viewbag.userid = @Request.Cookies["Userid"].value
```

Answer (score 0):

After registering, do you create a new session? Maybe the cookie is set to the `MinValue` for `Expires`, [which makes it a session cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie.expires%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Try this:

```
public void StoreCookie(Guid pid)
{
    var userCookie = new HttpCookie("Userid","B6EAF085-247B-46EB-BB94-79779CA44A14");
    userCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1); //...or something that fit your needs
    Response.Cookies.Remove("Userid");
    Response.Cookies.Add(userCookie);
}
```